# How to retrieve the list of 'Other Users' from Oracle SQL Developer in C#?

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Lately I have been trying to do all the basic operations of Database querying in C# for Oracle DB. I Have successfully been able to retrieve table and view data, but now I'm stuck.

To start with, I don't understand what exactly 'Other Users' means when I create a new connection, as follow :

[image]

What does these do? Also it would be great if anyone could suggest a way to retrieve this list?

Answer (score 1):

> How to retrieve the list of 'Other Users' from Oracle SQL Developer in C#?

Use the views provided by Oracle.

For example,

```
SELECT * FROM ALL_USERS;
```

From [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2114.htm#REFRN20302),

> ALL_USERS
>
> - ALL_USERS lists all users of the database visible to the current user.
>     This view does not describe the users (see the related views).
>
> Related Views
>
> - DBA_USERS describes all users of the database, and contains more columns than ALL_USERS.
> - USER_USERS describes the current user, and contains more columns than ALL_USERS.